# Disconnected node during Graph traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

I have been going through Breadth First Traversal at this link
[Breadth First Traversal](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/)

Now what if the graph structure is changed to this

[image: Graph]

The node 3 is now disconnected from the graph.
When traversal program is now used, it does'nt display vertex 3.
Is there a way where we can dispaly this vertex as well?

Comment: This is directly addressed in the link you gave. Search for "example Disconnected graph".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my understanding, BFS would keep looking for unvisited nodes as long as they exist; however, if this is not done, BFS only visits nodes in the connected component of the initial vertex. This seems to be more a matter of definition than an actual programming problem; simply restart the BFS implementation on unvisited nodes as long as they exist - if visiting of all connected components is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Many implementations of BFS/DFS assume implicitly that the graph is connected.

> Is there a way where we can dispaly this vertex as well?

Yes there is. If after finishing BFS still there are some unvisited vertices, enqueue them into the queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of all nodes, your graph search algorithm of choice (DFS/BFS) will discover the connected components one at a time.

You could do this in the following way.

For example, consider your example graph in which there are 4 nodes and edges between `0, 2`, `2, 0` and `1, 2` and node `3` has no incoming or outgoing edges.

You would have a list of nodes `{0, 1, 2, 3}`

And to discover all connected components, you would do the following:

```
Initialize visited array. Set all nodes to false

for node in list:
    if not visited: dfs(node)
```

where `dfs` is implemented in the usual way. Here when you run the code on our list `{0,1,2,3}`, the nodes `{0,1,2}` will be visited by the first `dfs` call and `0,1,2` will be marked visited. Then when we come across `3`, since it is not visited, there will be another `dfs` call.

Hope you get the idea.